# If I drop the same document into ElasticSearch again, is it going to reindex it?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

This is obviously a question about ES internals.

What I have is a custom search engine built on top of ES feeding it with data from multiple vendors. In order to find out if particular document has changed since last indexing (during e.g. periodic re-pulling the documents from vendors - there's no way to ask some vendors "give me only  documents changed since that date"), I'd have to check it somehow for modification and drop it into ES for indexing `iff` the document changed.

Question: does ES keep track of document checksums internally to see if it *actually* needs to re-index it? (of course I'm presuming that it's not some HTML where some fields, timestamps, etc. are updated dynamically on each `GET`).

If it did (that is, re-indexing identical documents has negligible amortized cost), that would simplify updates for me, obviously.

Comment: If you use the exact same document ID, then you can reindex the same document over and over and the search results won't change.

Comment: @Val: I understand, but my question is about the cost of reindexing the same document over and over.

Comment: How many documents are we talking and what's the frequency of that potential reindexing?

Comment: If you update with same ID and document is exactly the same then ES wont perform any operation and it will return **noop**. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document) on that.

Comment: You know what they say... ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). First, you should test your massive reindexing case and see how it's behaving. Then if you notice that it's potentially problematic then you can decide to invest some time in a more involved solution.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 that's for updates, not index operations. For index operations a [new document is always created](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-noop), so instead of re-indexing it's probably best to update with `detect_noop` enabled.

Comment: @Val, you are right, but if the OP uses update endpoint with upserts then document will be indexed if it does not exist or else ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Update API, you can detect no ops https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_detecting_noop_updates. You can see the source code for the no op here. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/update/UpdateRequestBuilder. Note the "extra work" comment. That's definitely something to consider.

Keep in mind the update API tends to be a lot slower than plain vanilla bulk inserts. Regular inserts in which you let ES increment the _version number when you index a document in the same index with the same id will be faster... but they'll also create GC and indexing pressure.

Comment: Also, in answer to "does ES keep track of document checksums internally to see if it actually needs to re-index it?" I'm pretty sure the answer there is no. If I understand https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/update/UpdateHelper.java#L178 correctly (I may not), this is reading the source doc as a map, comparing it to the doc you're inserting, and then evaluating whether or not they are the same thing (as opposed to using a system number of a checksum or that type of thing)